# gdb - gdbserver trace remote program execution

Tags: gdb, embedded-linux, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I am trying to extract the execution sequence of my program (something like a program counter) with gdb on my local computer (windows x86) and gdbserver on a remote target (arm-linux). The idea I had was to insert breakpoints at "important" lines of my source files (i.e.: at the beginning of a specific function, and more in general before and after a conditional statement) with a high ignore count for each breakpoint, and then check if a breakpoint was hit or not. I was actually able to receive the informations with this method, but there is a problem: the application behavior I am debugging depends on real-time, and this specific method slows down the program execution too much. Do you think I could use some other method with gdb? I stumbled upon tracepoints, wich seems the exact thing I am looking for, but I was not able to find some property like a "hit counter" for them. The gdb version I am currently using is 7.5.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: For kernel code, Consider using Kprobe and Jprobe on your target.  You can use these to keep those hit counters in the interesting parts of the code.  Not sure if a similar mechanism exists for user code, but I think it is possible.  http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/04/kernel-debugging-using-kprobe-and-jprobe/

Answer (score 0):

If your program execution must not be slowed down, you will probably need some HW tool. See these:

- [Keil real time trace](http://www.keil.com/arm/trace.asp)
- [Lauterbach PowerDebug](http://www.lauterbach.com/frames.html?bdmeth2.html)
- (probably other similar solutions)